# Mysql update the selected rows using single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have to select 3 rows from a table `book(id,book_id,status)` with status `status=0`.Initially all rows have `status` 0.So by using a select query.order by id and limit 3 I can select first 3 rows.The question is how can I update the selected rows status to 1 since they are selected.

Am using PHP, CodeIgniter and MySQL, can I do it in a single query?

Example:

```
id  book_id  status 
1     100      0
2     101      0
3     102      0
4     103      0
5     104      0
6     105      0
```

After selecting the first 3 rows the that rows's status should be updated to 1

```
id  book_id  status 
1     100      1
2     101      1
3     102      1
4     103      0
5     104      0
6     105      0
```

Comment: `Update book set status=1 where book_id in (Select book_id from book order by id limit 3);`

Comment: @Coderanonymous using this could I get the selected rows?

Comment: Yes you will, and status will also update to 1 for those book id's..:)

Comment: @Coderanonymous ok..I will try and let you know .Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6ef3/1)

```
UPDATE t JOIN (select id from t where status = 0 
                    order by id limit 3) t1 USING (id)
SET status=1 ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used MySQL's own [RAND(N)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function for this issue.

The reference says that:

> If an **integer** argument N is specified, it is used as the **seed value**:
>
> One **implication** of this behavior is that for **equal argument values**,
>   RAND(N) **returns** the same value each time, and thus produces a
>   **repeatable sequence of column values**.

So I can select a random set of records from the tables, and using the **same seed**, I can update exactly the same records without going through any of it.

And get something like this:

```
SELECT id, book_id 
FROM book 
WHERE status = 0 
ORDER BY RAND({your_seed}) 
LIMIT 0, 3;

UPDATE book 
JOIN ( 
  SELECT id 
  FROM book 
  WHERE status = 0 
  ORDER BY RAND({same_seed}) 
  LIMIT 0, 3 
) temp USING (id) 
SET status = 1;
```

This way you get your selection and also updated the exact same list.

Comment: Why would you want to order by a random field?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

```
UPDATE book
SET status = 1
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM book
  LIMIT 3
)
```

Comment: then how could I get the selected rows?

Comment: PHP's `mysql_query` will only return `TRUE` or `FALSE` for `UPDATE` statements. So I guess you'll need a separate query for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would do it

```
UPDATE book SET status = 1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM book ORDER BY id LIMIT 3)
```

Comment: You should add ORDER BY before LIMIT otherwise the result of this subquery is random.

Comment: Ahh missed that, fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
UPDATE TABLE NAME SET status = 1 WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM TABLE NAME  LIMIT 0,3)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: MySQL doesn't yet support LIMIT clause in subquery with IN

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved this, but I'm facing the same problem but my difference is that I want to select/update only 1 row. I did it using user variables like this:

```
SET @codigo:=NULL; -- the resulting value
UPDATE tproducto_codigos set canjeado=1, fecha_canjeo=NOW(), codigo=(@codigo:=codigo) 
 WHERE idtproducto_r=XXX AND canjeado=0 LIMIT 1; -- I only want the first row
SELECT @codigo as codigo; -- select the variable to get the value.
```

I hope this help you or someone else looking for this, because I think that this is quite common.